# appengine jpa cache level 2 performance is bad

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

appengine java sdk 1.6.4.1
datanucleus jpa2.0.0
datanucleus cache 3.0.1

hi all

i am using the DN cache level 2 plugin.

```
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="javax.cache"/>
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.cacheName" value="xxxxx"/>
```

i noticed a performance issue with a straight forward query.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("Select m.key from MessageUser m "
                + "where " + " m.userKeyList = :userKey "
                + "AND m.date > :date ORDER BY m.date DESC");
```

with the cache ON it execute in 1159 ms, cache OFF 86 ms.

something is clearly wrong. from the appstats trace the cache version is retrieving each entity in a serial manner from memcache.

any explanation on whether this is expected or have i stuffed up?

cache OFF

```
(1) 2012-04-12 06:19:38.737 "GET /timeline/status?id=49001&sincedate=1333485300" 200  real=86ms api=0ms overhead=0ms (6 RPCs) 

@11ms datastore_v3.RunQuery real=10ms api=241ms
@31ms datastore_v3.Get real=7ms api=208ms
@4ms datastore_v3.BeginTransaction real=4ms api=0ms
@52ms datastore_v3.Get real=7ms api=8ms
@65ms datastore_v3.Get real=4ms api=0ms
@78ms datastore_v3.Commit real=4ms api=0ms
```

cache ON

```
9) 2012-04-12 05:54:24.385 "GET /timeline/status?id=49001&sincedate=1333485300" 200 real=1159ms api=0ms overhead=0ms (109 RPCs) 
@13ms datastore_v3.RunQuery real=12ms api=241ms
@28ms memcache.Get real=2ms api=0ms
@33ms memcache.Get real=2ms api=0ms
@37ms memcache.Get real=3ms api=0ms
@42ms memcache.Get real=2ms api=0ms
@47ms memcache.Get real=2ms api=0ms
@50ms memcache.Get real=2ms api=0ms
@54ms memcache.Get real=2ms api=0ms
@57ms memcache.Get real=2ms api=0ms
<repeat this for another 50 or60 times
@3ms datastore_v3.BeginTransaction real=4ms api=0ms
@1126ms datastore_v3.Get real=5ms api=8ms
@1134ms memcache.Get real=3ms api=0ms
@1139ms memcache.Get real=2ms api=0ms
@1143ms datastore_v3.Get real=4ms api=0ms
@1153ms datastore_v3.Commit real=3ms api=0ms
```

the code that iterates the entity list

```
List<Message> list = messageDAO.findSinceDate(userKey, sinceDate);

JSONArray jsonList = new JSONArray();

for (Message message : list) {
item.put("id", message.getKey().getId());
    item.put("name", message.getName());
}
```

Comment: why not present your code where you are accessing the elements of the query result ? where you access them one-by-one? and then the log

Comment: @DataNucleus i have added the code that iterates the query results. as can be seen they are accessed in a iteration. what are thinking is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The query cache is probably only caching a result set's entity keys. The entities themselves are then looked up as they are accessed.

Here is some more information about query caches and how they can actually deteriorate performance. It is about Hibernate L2 caching but the datanucleus implmentation is probably similar.
http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/